Net exports equation
I have found the following equations:
Exports - Imports = Private Consumption - Private investments and savings + Taxes - Government Expenses = Net private savings + Net public deficit.
While I could understand the equation:
Exports - Imports = Net private savings + Net public deficit
I don't understand how the first equality sign could hold.
Could someone explain it?
Many thanks in advance

The two equations are essentially identical, but I believe two of the terms are around the wrong way.
The expression after the first equality is trying to break net private savings and the net public deficit into its constituent parts.
Net private savings should be = private investment and savings - private consumption
Net public deficit is =  Taxes - Government Expenses
In the top equation, Private Consumption and Private investments and savings need to be swapped around. Then the equality should hold.
Noting that net public deficit is negative if there is a deficit and positive if there is a surplus.

Thanks for your reply. There is still a point unclear to me. As far as I know Net private savings should be equal to S - I that is the remaining savings after deducting investment while in the equation you define it as S + I - C. Could you clarify this point?

Given they have grouped private investments and savings together I interpreted investments as say buying bonds or a long term deposit which is another form of saving essentially!

This would imply that you define net private savings as (S + I) - C wirh (S+ I) some sort of "broad" definition of savings (savings + bonds and long term deposit) while in the literature i've found a different definition, that is net privare savings = S - I with no reference to consumption. Still, what is the right definition of net private savings?
